# Toothpick Android. What's difference between singletonInScope vs instanceInScope?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, toothpick-di

Also i can't understand difference between

```
bind<String>().toProvider(Provider::class.java).singletonInScope()
```

and

```
bind<String>().toProvider(Provider::class.java).providesSingletonInScope()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bind<String>().toProvider(Provider::class.java).singletonInScope()
```

This line binds a String dependency using a provider class specified by Provider::class.java. It configures this binding to be a singleton in scope, meaning that only one instance of the String will be created and reused throughout the application. This is typically useful for objects that should be shared across the application and reused.

```
bind<String>().toProvider(Provider::class.java).providesSingletonInScope()
```

This line is similar to the first one, but it uses providesSingletonInScope() instead of singletonInScope(). In Koin, both of these methods are used to define singleton scoped dependencies, but providesSingletonInScope() is the more recent version introduced in Koin 3.x. It serves the same purpose as singletonInScope(), ensuring that only one instance of the dependency is created and reused throughout the application's lifecycle.